# Planner Tasks Api Call is failing with permission error sporadically

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm calling following endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/:planId/tasks?$select=id,title,appliedCategories,assignments,dueDateTime,createdDateTime,percentComplete`

Sometimes call is failing with permission error (not always) but other calls to `Graph API` are working fine with same `token`

the error Response is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f8b43045-b062-4e57-9c7f-c4380c197f55",
      "date": "2017-08-17T11:34:11"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the report. This problem should be resolved now, let us know if you are still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Hello Tarkan, I'm having the same issue. What is the fix?