# permissions needed for microsoft graph planner tasks?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), and enabled permissions include: User.ReadWrite, User.ReadBasic.All, Tasks.Read.Shared, Tasks.ReadWrite, Files.ReadWrite.All, etc.
Not: Group.Read.All (because Admin).

In the explorer I am logged in to my Office 365 account.
E.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` works fine.

I am not able to use any of the Planner endpoints. E.g.:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/planner/tasks

gives 403: You do not have the required permissions to access this item.
The same for e.g. `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/planner/plans/<id>/tasks`

Tried both `beta` and `v1.0`.
What additional permissions are needed?

PS. Tried it with two Office 365 accounts.
The Planner endpoints work fine with the sample account (=when not logged in).

PPS. Sounds similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734401/planner-tasks-api-call-is-failing-with-permission-error-sporadically), but in my case I have not seen a successful response yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/planneruser_list_tasks) state you need `Group.Read.All`. I get that requiring admin consent for this isn't great, but it looks like for now that's the answer. I'd suggest voting up [this UserVoice post](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15969922-add-a-my-groups-read-write-permission-that-do).

Comment: Indeed not great, but it does answer my question. thanks.